# Retrieve timestamp of the last message in channel

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I want to get the timestamp of the last message in a channel using my bot. The problem is that other bots can post in the channel too and according to the [FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesnt-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots) the following restriction exists:

> Bots talking to each other could potentially get stuck in unwelcome loops. To avoid this, we decided that bots will not be able to see messages from other bots regardless of mode.

I understand the reason, but I don't want really read these messages. I just want to know the last date of the post (because I don't want them post too often).

Comment: Do you manage all the bots in the channel?

Comment: no. Of course I could manage the problem by my code if there were only my bots